# how to change orientation of the iphone /ipod?

Tags: iphone

HI  All

i am using the device orientation for some functionality like as

in stating the as we run the app it should be  in the landscape mode and in this mode if we orientate  the phone in 90 angle than it should play some video than problem comes video play by default in the landscape mode but we need it in the portrait mode than for playing video in the portrait mode we put the code

```
[ mPlayer setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
```

like this even this method show a warning but it do work for playing the video in the portrait  mode.

now what is the problem :-as we start the app the screen we were showing in the starting of the app just comes and disaapper and it just starts playing the video and not come to that screen we even use the default rotation function to make it usable but it doesn't work

any suggestion thanks 
Balraj Verma

Comment: If your code is as readable as your questions, I'd rather not be your teammate ;)

Answer (score 1):

The method setOrientation is a private API (SDK 3.2) and should not be used.

Instead change the coordinate system with:

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);
```

Of course you may have to add some code before and after but I let you find some examples on StackOverflow.

Good luck!